# How to extract string after last occurrence of a word in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have my string column in one of my Hive tables as

```
select * from
(
select "edition_xx/news/radio_today_news_xx" as my_column
union all 
select "edition_xx/news/news/television_1.3" as my_column
) A
```

I would like to extract the part of string that is followed after `news/` . So my output column would look like

```
radio_today_news_xx
television_1.3
```

How can I extract this using regex in Hive? Note that `news/` can occur X times and I want the string after its last occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `split()`:

```
select  split(my_column,'(news/)+')[1] 
from
(
select "edition_xx/news/radio_today_news_xx" as my_column
union all 
select "edition_xx/news/news/television_1.3" as my_column
) A;
```

This regexp means `news/` one or more times

Result:

```
radio_today_news_xx
television_1.3
Time taken: 37.218 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: this assumes the desired output is always at the end of the string, which is not true per the OP's description i think.

Comment: yes, this logic will fail if I had a record with value `edition_xx/news/radio_today/news_xx` , in which case I will need `radio_today/news_xx` in output. But the logic will return `news_xx`

Comment: though i think splitting on `reverse('news/')` instead of `'/'` will work for me

Answer (score 0):

using split to get the last occurrence

```
select split(A.my_column,'news\/')[size(split(A.my_column,'news\/'))-1] lt
    from
    (
    select "edition_xx/news/radio_today_news_xx" as my_column
    union all 
    select "edition_xx/news/news/television_1.3" as my_column
    union all
    select "edition_xx/news/radio_today/news_xx" as my_column
    )
```

output

```
radio_today_news_xx
television_1.3
radio_today/news_xx
```